# Auto-adding pages with node.js on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

It would be wonderful if you could help me with this!
I'm using node.js and heroku to deply an app and I'm changing my web.js file everything I add a new post. This was fine earlier, but with more pages, it's starting to get out of hand. I'm wondering if I could automate this?
Eg, this is what my web.js file looks like now:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var htmlfile = "index.html";
var app = express(express.logger());

//day 7 and so on.. till day 15.

var day6 = "./100/day6/day6.html";
app.get('/day6', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(day6).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var day5 = "./100/day5/day5.html";
app.get('/day5', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(day5).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var day4 = "./100/day4/day4.html";
app.get('/day4', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(day4).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var day3 = "./100/day3/day3.html";
app.get('/day3', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(day3).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var day2 = "./100/day2/day2.html";
app.get('/day2', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(day2).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var challengehtmlfile = "100.html";
app.get('/100-day-challenge', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(challengehtmlfile).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var bloghtmlfile = "blog.html";
app.get('/blog', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(bloghtmlfile).toString();
response.send(html);
});


app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlfile).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Comment: maybe write a BASH script to insert those lines with file names as variables.. And you can just call the script to automatically insert the lines whenever you write a new page

Comment: just use some database and query by id in url, why not?

Comment: I'm quite noob at this, how can one do that specifically?

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your comment notification. I put up a way that might you help just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to add much more pages, it is not a good idea to add one route per page. Better way is to use pattern matching in your routing. For example,

```
app.get('/day/:num', function(request, response) {
var day = "./100/day" + request.params.num + "/day" + request.params.num + ".html";
var html = fs.readFileSync(day).toString();
response.send(html);
});
```

Now this route would match any number of days. Only thing you would have to change is the URL. Instead of '/day3', you should access '/day/3'. 
In `/day/:num`, `:num` is just a variable name in the url. You access that variable through request.params.num. Then you construct the filename with that information. Hope this would clean up your script. :)
For more info, check express api here (http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code and save it as "insert.sh".

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$1
day=day$1

sed -i "/express(express.logger());/avar ${day} = \"./100/${day}/${day}.html\";\napp.get('/${day}', function(request, response) {\nvar html = fs.readFileSync(${day}).toString();\nresponse.send(html);\n});\n" $2
```

This script takes two parameters: # of days and file name. For example,

```
bash insert.sh 3 yournode.js
```

This command will insert the necessary code for day3 in your node.js file. I assumed you want to add those lines after `express.logger()` line. If you want to put the code after a different line, simply replace `express(express.logger());` in the script to anything you want. Please let me know.